# which is a better way to save into sql server , directly from csv , excel or converting datasources into xml format?

Tags: sql-server, xml, excel, csv

Assume my stored procedure has -

insert into tablename (fieldA ,fieldB ,fieldC ,) values (X ,Y ,Z  ).

Supose there are 100 fields. user only gives values of 3 to me which is really unpredictable.Making other 97 fields null.
So wats the best way to save my data into sql . The datasource could be a csv file or excel or user can enter from UI as well. 
Is an intermediate xml required in all cases to make key value pair and then save into the database (sql). Or there is some application of ado.net into it?
Please help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Excel is a horrible idea; it likes reformatting your data for you, whether you want it to or not.

XML is an extremely bulky format, and is vulnerable to a small error (missing angle bracket or closing tag) causing major problems.

Delimited files need to have the data strictly defined so as not to contain your delimiter(s), but then you can use [BCP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx) or [BULK INSERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx) with a format file.  At least choose a rare delimiter, like [unit separator](http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-control-characters/unit-separator-ascii-code-31.html), or, if you HAVE to, tabs, pipes, or tildes.

Fixed width files take up more space than delimited, but don't generally have the delimiters in the text issues, and you can again use [BCP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx) or [BULK INSERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx) with a format file.

GUI's aren't terribly good for 100 fields.

Comment: hi ! I have such a requirement where in i can get the values in my tables from various sources. User can provide me either an excel , or a csv file or he may enter few of his favourites from UI which are unpredictable .  I m actually kind of new so wondered about which is the best way to store data in sql coming from various datasources(excel,csv,formbased ui)

Comment: Push back on the requirement.  Then start looking up each type of import separately; Excel "can" be saved as tab-delimited, but good luck with getting consistent data formats.  You need to end up with a good schema that enforced data consistency, and put your data there, regardless of where it comes from.

Comment: Ok thanks.. So no (excel/csv/user inputs) required to be mapped on  xml  and then pushed back in database?

Comment: No, you absolutely do not _have_ to map everything to XML.  You _can_, but I'd rate that as much more cost than potential benefit.

Comment: so i will have to write code for each seperately depending upon my input source type!....  And does ado.net helps into this ? sory i m just new into this so clearing out my things!

Comment: Yes; but that's no different than before.  You were going to have to do separate conversions to XML based on source, and THEN do XML to SQL.  Now you're going source to SQL; one less conversion.  Again, push back on your users; offer them one to three well defined ways of putting data in; don't accept any format they feel like giving you today, and wanting the data in the database yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

Because 'good form' dictates that you scrub data prior to writing it to a database you will want to code for each independent data source.  MSSQL (I assume you are using SQL Server) has some mechanisms to allow BULK INSERT but that should be done in cases where data is known to be clean.

I would recommend not allowing NULL(s) set your default field values to something useful. write code for each data source.

Comment: hi @terary - i am very confused .. :(  I want to put excel/csv/user input into sql. i m very confused whether to use xml or bulkcopy ..  If i convert all these sources into xml and then put into database ... Is it beneficial or  a overhead ?? pls pls make me clear. M stuck!!!!!!

Comment: Bulk copy has an out-of-the box function that allows you to gulp the entire file.  However, it is not robust and will choke on any errors.  Reformat your data simply to put in a database - is 'ok'.  But requires 30% more work than simple creating a flat file.  When you are creating a flat file you can 'bulk copy' that file into the database (or better) simple write code to insert record by record.  Then for records rejected you can easily see what you need to scrub for.

Comment: -flat file means here? Of course I need to clean the input source file excel or csv and den dump in my db.. M unclear by your answer..

Comment: Ok, when I clean data, I use some programming language.  That language usually supports db interactions. So instead of writing to the file, insert into the database.  If the databse failes the one record log it, and move on to the next record.